# Nautilus sftp via command line

Tags: nautilus, sftp, nautilus-script

I regularly connect to a server via ssh. Lately I've started copying files to and from it, and I find scp very annoying, mainly because bash cannot auto complete over ssh.

I find the `connect to server...` option very useful, as I can drag and drop and everything. However, it is very annoying to type each time `nautilus sftp://server` (or fill the dialog box) and then enter username and password, and then to `cd`  to the desired folder. Is there a way to do it in one line, something like

`nautilus ntfs://server -u user ...`

I couldn't find it anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as the correct one ;)

Comment: @Bruno Pereira I wanted to, but apparently I have to wait 2 days

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer by myself.

`nautilus sftp://USER@SERVER/PATH` will open a Nautilus window on the path I need.